# Woher kommt "mein lieber Herr Gesangverein"?

Tags: idiom

Wo kommt eigentlich die Redewendung "mein lieber Herr Gesangverein" her?

Comment: Heißt das nicht "Gesang**s**verein"?

Comment: Both *Gesangsverein* and *Gesangverein* are correct.

Comment: @User, Quelle? Duden nennt nur den Gesang**s**verein https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gesangsverein

Comment: @Iris 1. ***Your own link;*** Just scroll down; https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gesangverein. 2. Canoo: http://canoo.net/services/Controller?input=Gesangverein&MenuId=Search&service=canooNet&lang=de. 3. Wiktionary:https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Gesangverein. 4. Pons: https://mobile.pons.com/de/dict/search/mobile-results/deen/Gesangverein. 5. Dict.cc: https://www.dict.cc/?s=Gesangverein

Comment: @User, ich bin überzeugt. Danke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Beste, was ich dir als Antwort anbieten kann, stammt von einer [Dokumentation von n-tv](https://www.n-tv.de/wissen/frageantwort/Woher-kommt-der-Herr-Gesangsverein--article336659.html):

> "Es handelt sich dabei um einen Ausruf der Verwunderung, des
>   Erstaunens, der Verärgerung, der Anerkennung, der Verblüfftheit, der
>   Überraschung. Grundsätzlich ist nicht auszuschließen, dass die
>   Redensart in Analogie zu Redensarten mit gleich lautendem Beginn und
>   identischer Satzstruktur gebildet ist, etwa zu 'Mein lieber Schwan'
>   oder 'Mein lieber Scholli'." (Rebecca Nöcker)

Fazit: De facto weiß die Germanistik nicht, woher das Idiom kommt.

Answer (score 4):

Der "Herrengesangsverein" (Langform: "Teuerster Herrengesangsverein der Welt") war eine spöttisch-abfällige Bezeichnung des Reichtages unter Hitler, da dort – außer die Nationalhymne zu singen – nichts von den Abgeordneten verlangt wurde.

Kritik war im sog. ›3. Reich‹ eine Sache des Flüsterwitzes, daher waren Umschreibungen wie "Mein lieber Herrengesangsverein" für aktuelle Regimehandlungen und davon ausgehend für allgemeines Missverständnis oder Erstaunen verbreitet. Und da in Berlin die Endung -en häufig Stumm ist, verbreitete sich dieser aus Berlin stammende Ausdruck dann als "Herr Gesangsverein", während es in Berlin immer noch der Ausdruck "Mein Lieber Herr⁠ɲ̊gesangsverein" ist, je nach Soziolekt auch mit /j/ statt dem ersten G.

Comment: Das ist immerhin mal eine interessante Theorie. Ich habe aber noch ein bisschen Probleme damit, zu verstehen, wieso man, wenn man flüsternd-verdeckt Naziregimekritik üben will, ein (spöttisches) Wort für den Reichstag benützt. Wäre nicht ein spöttisches Wort für das Regime selbst angemessener?

Answer (score 2):

Hier ist eine weitere Erklärung: https://www.swr.de/blog/1000antworten/antwort/11943/woher-kommt-%E2%80%9Emein-lieber-herr-gesangverein/

> Das ist auf das Alte Testament zurückzuführen. Dort steht: "Du sollst den Namen
>   Gottes, Deines Herrn, nicht unnütz brauchen." Deswegen haben sich sehr viele Euphemismen eingeschlichen: Man sagt also etwas Ähnliches und vermeidet es doch.
>
> Sie kennen vielleicht „potz Blitz!“ Das hieß ursprünglich „Gottes Blitz soll dich treffen!“ „Potz Blitz“ klingt ein wenig wie „Gotts Blitz“ und man vermeidet damit den Namen Gottes.
>    Auch „Mein lieber Herr“ ist eigentlich eine Anrufung Gottes. Aber das soll man ja nicht tun, wenn man flucht, sich wundert oder ärgert. Also sagt man etwas anderes, z. B. „mein lieber Schwan“. „Mein lieber Herr Gesangverein“ kam im 19. Jahrhundert auf, als Gesangvereine sehr beliebt waren. Man setzte also einfach ein anderes Wort ein, das durchaus unsinnig sein konnte. Man vermied auf diese Weise eine Gotteslästerung.

Comment: Erscheint mir unplausibel, da das Vermeiden von Gotteslästerungen ein typisch mittelalterliches Phänomen ist. Im 19. Jahrhundert war man da, in Folge der Aufklärung schon lange drüber hinweg.

Answer (score -1):

Eine weitere Theorie findet sich [unter diesem Link](https://www.eine-zeitung.net/2014/05/17/e-wie-wissen-ii/). Demnach tätigte Kaiser Wilhelm I. 1872 den Ausspruch: „Auch Ihnen möchte ich ganz besonderen Dank aussprechen, mein lieber Herr Gesangsverein!“ um so seinen Kammerdiener Karl-Heinz Gesangsverein im Rahmen einer öffentlichen Rede zu würdigen.

Comment: Dazu würde mich ja noch als Ergänzung interessieren, wie viele Menschen Ende des 19.Jh. den Familiennamen _Gesangsverein_ trugen. Der dtv-Namensatlas hat jedenfalls keinen Eintrag dazu. Eventuell gibt es ja auch noch  historische Quellen, in denen die Angestellten des Kaisers aufgelistet sind...

Comment: Ich halte das selbst für unwahrscheinlich, wollte das aber im Sinne der hier stattfindenden Theoriefindung nicht unerwäht lassen.

Comment: Die kaiserliche Haushaltung ist gut dokumentiert. Es gab keinen Kammerdiener dieses Namens. Interessanterweise gab es aber eine Kammerzofe namens Gisa Engelbein, die der Kaiser sehr schätzte. Es heißt, wenn ihn die Regierungsgeschäfte mit allerlei steifen Diplomaten und Beamten zu sehr anödeten, ließ Kaiser Wilhelm die Zofe rufen: "Schickt mir her die Gisa Engelbein!" Weil aber das Verhältnis der beiden als unschicklich empfunden wurde, formte man den Spruch am Hofe dezenterweise leicht um, und so wurde "Mein lieber Herr Gesangverein" daraus.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Hast du dafür eine Quelle? Mir scheint,  wir nähern uns hier so langsam einer plausiblen Erklärung an.

Comment: @scienceponder   Ja, Wissenschaft ist ein mühsames Geschäft, aber sie lohnt sich. Quellen: Ich schau mal nach... ich meine, da war in den Akten der kaiserlichen Haushaltung im Berliner Staatsarchiv irgendwo eine Notiz...

Comment: In satira veritas - https://www.eine-zeitung.net/2014/05/17/e-wie-wissen-ii/